# How to bind a gird view on button click in windows form using c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

My problem is more complex than you think!!

Let me explain first.

I have form say "Form1". It has one grid view that contains details of Items.
On the same form i have a button "Search". If i click on Search button another form opens say "SearchForm"

"SerchForm" has one textbox and button("Search").

Now i write the name of item in textbox of "SearchForm" and click on "Search", matching item should be shown in the grid view of "Form1".

Is it possible in windows form?? How??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please don't call DataGridViews GridViews. They are different! How does the search work? Do you really want DataBinding? Do you want to keep the 2nd From open after the search?

Comment: Are you wanting to scroll to the item that was found, if any, in the DataGridView?

Comment: no i want 2nd form must be hide after completion of serach

Comment: It's actually a lot less complicated than you think.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know a call method in parent form, then using delegate and event.

1. SearchForm
   : Make event and call it when 'Search' button is clicked.

   ```
   // Make delegate and event
   public delegate void DisplayData(string aMessage);
   public event DisplayData ShowData;

   private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       // Call event
       ShowData(txtMessage.Text);
   }
   ```
2. Form1
   : Make method which you want to use and link it to event.

   ```
   SearchForm searchForm = new SearchForm();

   private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       // Add event
       searchForm.ShowData += new SearchForm.DisplayData(Search);
   }
   private void Search(string aMessage)
   {
       // Input gridview add code here
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Use a property in the SearchForm and retrieve it from the Form1

SearchForm :

```
public int GetSelectedItem { get; set; }
```

set the value of this property after you click the search button in SearchForm

Form1:

```
SearchForm searchForm = new SearchForm();
searchForm.ShowDialog();
int _selectedItem = searchForm.GetSelectedItem;
```